firebase app hosting CNAME not working with domain provider
I having trying to add a CNAME provided by firebase with my domain provider (strato) without success.It is somethign like
CNAME _acme-challenge_hsfgdhsdhghdsd.mydomain.com. 
VALUE xxxxx-f64df44d13333.10.authorize.certificatemanager.goog. 

I cannot use this CNAME with my domain provider. It seems to be too long. I have tried _acme-challenge_hsfgdhsdhghdsd without success.
The only one that works is _acme-challenge but I don't know if this is correct.

Who is your domain provider? Maybe they expect you to enter just "_acme-challenge_hsfgdhsdhghdsd" (without the domain part).

@MaksVerver even that seems too long. Only _acme-challenge csn be saved

The values are both valid. Per @maks-verver, you can omit the domain from the name value. If you're having an issue adding this record using your provider (strato) then you should contact the provider.
